# How do I post JSON data into deeper layers within my API?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This week I have learned to fetch data from an API with javascript and jQuery.
Until now, I've only had to fetch from deeper levels within objects (which I've succeeded at), but I still don't know how to post to specific elements within other objects.

I'm currently working on a smart home project, where I'm the one responsible for the web application.
All device controllers have got a 'favourite' button, which is the one that triggers this function to either favourise or un-favourise the pressed object:

```
function toggle_favourite(id) {
    fetch('../../api/objects?id=' + id)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.objects[id-1].favourite == true) {
                // set .favourite to 'false'
                put(id, {
                    favourite: false
                })
            } else {       
                // set .favourite to 'true'
                put(id, {
                    favourite: true
                })
            }
        })
    })
}

function put(id, data) {
    fetch('../../api/objects?id='+id, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
}
```

The data that I'm trying to change is [this favourite value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8tM4.jpg).

How do I manouver over to this 'favourite' value with fech/'PUT'?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "move over to this favorite"?

Comment: @Tomalak I need to change the 'favourite' value that's shown in this picture: https://imgur.com/a/OOboX5x , but I don't know how since it's not in the first layer.

Comment: Nobody can answer this with the given info. This is something that depends to 100% on the API you're using (i.e. the server-side code) and all you are showing here is client-side code.

Comment: @Tomalak Here is the entire api/objects: https://pastebin.com/eFAhucJK. I need to change the 'favourite' value with fetch, but I don't know how. I've succesfully read it with data.objects[0].favourite, but I don't know how to post to it.

Comment: You still don't understand. It depends on the server-side *code*, not on the object you have stored on the server. The code that handles PUT requests to the `../../api/objects` URL dictates how a PUT request has to look like in order to do what you want.

Comment: @Tomalak Okay, now I understand what you're saying. I will try contacting the API programmer to see what I shall do then.

Comment: Isn't the API open source? Isn't it documented somewhere?

Comment: @Tomalak It wasn't a problem with the API at all, it's just that I didn't know how to change a value that isn't top level. Found out that you just have to fetch the entire object, change the part you need to change and then 'PUT' the entire object back to update it :)

Comment: I was suspecting something like that, but without seeing the API docs I did not want to take guesses.

Answer (score 1):

If the value isn't top level, you have to fetch the entire object, change the part you want to and then 'PUT'/'POST' the object at the end.

For this example, I fetched the entire object and saved it into a 'const', went through it and changed the 'favourite' value, and at the end I 'PUT' everything back into the object like so:

```
async function getObject(id){
    const response = await fetch('../../api/objects?id='+id)
    return response.json()
}
        
async function saveObject(){
    const data = await getObject(int_id)
    $.each(data, function(index, objects){
        $.each(objects, function(index, values){
            if (values.favourite == true ){
                values.favourite = false
            }
            else{
                values.favourite = true
            }
        })
    })
    put(int_id, data)
    function put(id, data) {
        fetch('../../api/objects?id='+id, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Success:', data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            })
    }
}
```